# Trying to Assign Variable Value to Struct Element. At first variable has right value, but struct element has garbage value

Tags: c++, variables, struct, variable-assignment

```
//Program tracks 10 students
//Prompts for first and last names
//Collect 4 grades from each student: final exam, 2 quizzes, and class project
//Report will display names w/ individual scores, class average, and highest grade

//Each students individual grade will be calculated with grade weights
/*Grade Weights
-2 Quizzes @ 15% each
-1 Final Exam @ 20% 
-1 Class Project @ 50% 
*/

#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    struct goodStudent
    { 
        string fname;
        string lname;
        double exam;
        double quiz1;
        double quiz2;
        double project;
        float realgrd;      //(sum of ALL grade weights
    };

    int pupil = 10;                 //represents # of students in class
    goodStudent student[pupil];     //value of 'pupil' subs as value used to define #elements of student[]

    //******Prompt for Student Names:
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < pupil; i++)
    {
        cout << "\n Student " << i+1 << " First Name:  ";
        cin >>student[i].fname;

        cout << "\t Student " << i+1 << " Last Name:  ";
        cin >>student[i].lname;
    }

    cout <<"--------------------------------";

    //*****Grade Collection and Weights Prompt
    int grade;
    double quizweight,examweight,projweight,cuml;


    for (grade = 0; grade < pupil; grade++)
    {
        cout <<"\n \t Student"<<" "<< grade+1; 
        cout << "\n Enter Quiz Grade 1: \n"; 
        cin >>student[grade].quiz1;

        cout <<"\n Enter Quiz 2 Grade:\n ";
        cin >>student[grade].quiz2; 
        quizweight = ((student[grade].quiz1)+(student[grade].quiz2))*.30;

        cout <<"\n Enter Final Exam Grade:\n ";
        cin >> student[grade].exam;
        examweight =(student[grade].exam)*.20;

        cout <<"\n Enter Project Grade:\n ";
        cin >>student[grade].project;
        projweight =(student[grade].project)*.50;

        //MATH GETS JUMBLED UP HERE.IDK had to do ALOT of conversion and revisions.... ;(
        cuml = ((projweight)+(examweight)+(quizweight));

        double adjust=((cuml/130))*100;//130 is max pts student can earn across all assignments
        cout<<adjust;
        adjust=student[grade].realgrd;

        cout<<"\n\n\n"<<student[grade].realgrd;
        /*
        FOR SOME REASON PROGRAM DOESN'T LIKE PUTTING ASSIGNED VALUES INTO ARRAY STRUCT..
        fix=student[grade].realgrd;

        cout<<"\n\nLet's Try it AGAIN:  "<<student[grade].realgrd;

        cout<<"\nGrade For Student "<<grade+1<<"\tIs A: "<<fix;
        */
        system("PAUSE");
    }
}
```

Ok. So I'm trying to assign a value to an element within a struct array. I printed the value out before it's to be assigned to the element within the array. It's the value I want, but when I print the array to check if the same value is there, it's a long garbage number like 7.6674323e-309. I even changed the struct member "realgrd" to double, float, and long variable types to see if that would change the output, but that doesn't work.

[image]

Comment: just tag c++ not c. these are two different language

Comment: You start indexing your `student` array using the variable `pupil`, and then a little later (after entering the names), you switch to indexing the list by grade.  I suspect you wanted to collect the grades for each student, so you might want rethink your approach.  Consider collecting all the data for a student at one time (which means everything goes inside the outer `pupil` for loop).

Comment: You never assign a value to `realgrd`, perhaps `adjust = student[grade].realgrd;` is backward? https://ideone.com/z5FTPx

Comment: step through with a debugger

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you have this line backwards

```
 adjust=student[grade].realgrd;
```

you mean

```
student[grade].realgrd = adjust;
```

Comment: I tried it and it works. When I read the 1st line in my head, to me it says 'the value of adjust is assigned to the nth student's real grade'. When I read the 2nd line, to me it says 'student n's real grade is assigned to adjust'. Both statements to me make logical sense, unless I'm missing a subtle C/C++ rule.

Comment: Every other assignment in your program is right side assigning to left side. Why would this one be different?

Comment: in almost all programming languages (certainly in all c-like ones) `x = y` means 'change the value of x so that it now contains y'